# Imported or Loaded Modules in Runspace, still 'Connect-AzureRMAccount' throws 'command not recognised as cmdlet..'

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, runspace

As the question is quite intuitive, I'm trying to use AzureRM in my asp .net core web application. I've created InitialStateSession and Runspace as follows.

Runsapce Version: 7.0.3

Installed the AzureRM module from powershellGallary.

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;
iss.ImportPSModule("AzureRM");
Runspace rso = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
rso.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rso;
ps.AddScript("Connect-AzureRmAccount");
var res = ps.Invoke();
var errors = ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
rso.Close();
```

when I run the code I get the following error

`{The term 'Connect-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.}`

**While using the same commands directly on PowerShell works like charm. but it doesn't with c# code.**

I even tried Importing the module like below.

`iss.ImportPSModule("path to the module.psm1 or .psd1");` and

`ps.AddScript("Import-Module azureRM");`

`ps.AddScript("Import-Module azureRM.Profile");`

I've checked for the paths it is looking for the module and it included the modules path using this.

`var path = rso.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("env:PSModulePath");`

I've installed `azureRM.Netcore` also as there was some issue with versions.

Each tries to fix this is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem is really tricky and difficult to deal with. A lot of solutions have been tried but ultimately failed. I can only deal with this problem in a different way, and hope to inspire you.

Answer (score 1):

After a long period of exploration and research, I found that the same error message will appear when both `Connect-AzAccount` and `Connect-AzureRmAccount` are executed, but the local PowerShell execution is normal, which is a strange phenomenon.

Checked a lot of information and closed issues on github. The solution is nothing more than installing `AzureRM.NetCore` or other vs plug-ins, but they have no effect. And the official does not have a good explanation.

In the end, I changed my mind, hoping to help you realize this function. Finally, if it succeeds, the command is executed through `cmd`.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Powershell Connect-AzureRmAccount &exit");

        p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did not try to execute your solution though. I tried the same code as posted in the question with Az and it works very well. And I started migrating to Az already as anyhow azureRM will be deprecated after 2 years.

Comment: @Venkateshdharavath Okay, I'm glad you can solve the problem with `Connnect-AzAccount`. When  using `powershell` successfully in the local, but fails by code, my solutions can be tried.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jason Pan

Comment: @Venkateshdharavath Although you passed `Az` to solve your problem, but because there is a problem on `AzureRm`, which leads to the problem, my solution is to help you solve the problem of `AzureRm`, of course. Az` also works.